# How to pass Dataframe column values dynamically from JSON file in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am creating dataframe using below code it is working as expected.

my dataset is `'testdata'` :

```
1|123
2|223
3|323
4|423

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext,SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df_transac = spark.createDataFrame(sc.textFile("testdata").map( lambda x: x.split("|")[:2]).map( lambda r: Row( testA = r[0],testb = r[1])))
df_transac.show()

+---------+---------+
|   testA | testB   |
+---------+---------+
|      123|        1|
|      223|        2|
|      323|        3|
|      423|        4|
+---------+---------+
```

Above dataframe creating time testA,testB is hardcoded column names, but I want to take those values from json, so i tried following way.
my json file `testjson.json:`

```
{
    "column1":"testcolumn1"
    ,"column2":"testcolumn2"
}
```

Then I try to create data frame by executing below code , 
but its throwing  error.

```
import json
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext,SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row
with open(testjson.json) as spec_data:
    jsn = json.load(spec_data)
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df_transac = spark.createDataFrame(sc.textFile("testdata").map( lambda x: x.split("|")[:2]).map( lambda r: Row( jsn['column1'] = r[0], jsn['column2'] = r[1])))
```

throwing error like :SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression.

my expected output is:

```
+-----------+-----------+
|testcolumn1|testcolumn2|
+-----------+-----------+
|          1|        123|
|          2|        223|
|          3|        323|
|          4|        423|
+-----------+-----------+
```

Please help on this how can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Separate out your createDataFrame() call. Write all the functions that you are doing outside createDataFrame and then pass the dict object to it. You'll understand yourself what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As the exception says - you cannot use expressions as keywords so this:

```
Row( jsn['column1'] = r[0], jsn['column2'] = r[1])
```

is not a valid Python code.

You can use alternative constructor and then apply arguments:

```
Row(jsn['column1'], jsn['column2'])(r[0], r[1])
```

but in general there it would be better to

```
tmp = spark.read.option("delimiter", "|").csv("testdata")
df = tmp.select(tmp.columns[2:]).toDF(jsn['column1'], jsn['column2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df_transac = spark.createDataFrame(sc.textFile("testdata").map( lambda x: x.split("|")[:2]).map( lambda r: Row( jsn['column1'] = r[0], jsn['column2'] = r[1])))
```

Instead of above code,use below code to resolve the issue.

```
c1=spec['column1']
c2=spec['column2']
a=sc.textFile("testdata").map( lambda x: x.split("|")[:2])
data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(a,[c1, c2])
```